# Count exchanged bytes per TCP connection

Tags: linux, kernel, tcp, netstat, tcpdump

I need to get a table updated with the exchanged bytes (Rx and/or Tx) for each ESTABLISHED TCP connection on a linux machine (well, at least, a list of connections (port ranges), thus not actually *all*)

My dream would be to extend 'netstat' and have these counters as additional columns.
But where to find these infos?
Maybe this is available in the kernel ? /proc? 
*nix tool? 
Should I stick to libpcap?

Hints:
What I *CAN'T* do is to start a tcpdump for each connections.
What I WOULD avoid is having to run this *something* as root (well, sudo can be discussed)

Thank you for all your inputs...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend IPTABLES counter, you can show packet counter for each rule in iptables using

```
iptables -nL -v
```

the option -v here shows you the packet and byte count.

The only catch is you need to have a matching rule ( -j ACCEPT ) for each connection entry.

For example below rule counts all TCP packets generated from my linux box.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Now I only need to run

```
iptables -nL -v
```

to see the bytes and packet count used.

Comment: Sweet! this is totally new input...I could use it, again it is only in 'root' mode but could lead to something, I'll give it a try (of course 'iptables -A OUPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT' won't make it on my box, since i do not have any chain/target/match by that name, right?)

Comment: My bad, should be
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

If you want something fancy and graphical you might take a look at `ntop` - it's in most distro's apt / yum / whatever.

It monitors the network traffic creating nice graphs and charts on a per-connection, protocol, host, etc basis and displays it all through your web browser (has a built in web server).

It's nice, but fairly heavyweight.

Comment: That is indeed very valuable input as it is a complete product and clearly reproduce the output I want to see, just like: http://iptraf.seul.org/shots/iptraf-tcpudp.gif  but again, this is libpcap oriented and I _have_ to be root (and indeed fairly heavyweight)